# Большой ассоциативный массив PHP из MySQL (> 20 000 строк ), превышение лимитов либо по памяти, либо по времени

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Есть БД MySQL, 20 000 + записей, каждая строка - это 20 столбцов с разным форматом данных (int, varchar, text, date, time ... )
Мне поставили задачу одним нажатием кнопки выгрузить содержимое и записать в excel.
Выборку пытался делать по 100, 1000, 2000 строк, в любом случае процесс занимает очень много времени, и в итоге получаю ошибку об отсутствии памяти, либо timeout.
Существует ли способ создания больших ассоциативных массивов в PHP > 20 тыc элементов ???

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь писать по-русски грамотно. Я вообще не мог понять по заголовку, о чем речь идет (отредактировал для повышения вероятности ответа).

Comment: а нажатие кнопки где должно быть?... если на фронтенде, то просто пусть эта кнопка посылает асинхронный запрос, который просто добавляет джобу в очередь. А джоба запускается на сервере без ограничения по времени. как будет готова - сообщаете по веб-сокету клиенту что все готово(ну или опрашиваете периодически сервер о готовности задачи)

Comment: Если выбрать «потоковый» формат, такой как csv (его тоже можно открывать в excel), то можно генерировать файл вообще бесконечной длины. Не нужно создавать большие ассоциативные массивы, нужно брать данные по чуть-чуть и записывать в файл тоже по чуть-чуть

Comment: Когда-то давно, сделал примерно по следующей логике... Кнопка отправляет запрос о начале через ajax. Код обрабатывает N строк, сохраняет файл и возвращает ответ. Если ответ успешный, то опять отправляется ajax, только уже с номером строки, с которой надо продолжить выборку для следующей обработки. Код отрабатывает и дописывает уже в существующий файл. И если строки закончились, то возвращает ссылку на файл и js перекидывает на его скачивание.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема первая -- таймаут

Если вы собираетесь делать что-то грандиозное по нажатию на кнопку в веб-интерфейсе, то вам надо создать *Задание*, которое будет выполнятся отдельным процессом без ограничения на время выполнения (например по крону или через консьюмера очереди). Когда отдельный процесс завершит Задание, он пометит его как завершённое. Всё время пока отдельный процесс кряхтит переваривая ваши тысячи строк, пользователь веб-интерфейса просто спрашивает время от времени "ну как там? уже готово?" (polling). Такие пользовательские запросы выполняются быстро и не отваливаются по таймауту.

Проблема вторая -- лимит памяти

Если ваш скрипт ворочает очень большими данными, вам следует постараться сделать так, чтобы можно было зафиксировать часть сделанной работы, освободить память и приступить к следующей части.

В вашем случае можно получать данные по несколько строк (например по 1000), записывать в конец csv-файла (как вам советуют в комментариях) и повторять это пока строки в таблице не закончатся. Но помните, что этим должен заниматься отдельный процесс, а не обработчик пользовательского запроса.

Попробую изобразить, как мог бы происходить такой процесс:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете сделать разбор Задач через постоянно запускающийся cron-скрипт или использовать gearman или брокер очередей вроде rabbitmq.

Comment: Большое спасибо за советы.